# MarkLogic: find by property value

Tags: javascript, node.js, marklogic

I have a MarkLogic 8 database:

```
declareUpdate();
var book0 = {
  id: fn.generateId({qwe: 'book'}),
  username: 'book',
  password: 'pass'
};
var book1 = {
  id: fn.generateId({asd: 'book'}),
  username: 'user',
  password: 'pass1'
};
xdmp.documentInsert(
       'zz' + book0.id,
       book0,
       xdmp.defaultPermissions(),
       ['qwe']);
xdmp.documentInsert(
       'xx' + book1.id,
       book1,
       xdmp.defaultPermissions(),
       ['qwe']);
```

So I want to find them by name with the Node.js API:

```
var db = marklogic.createDatabaseClient(connection.connInfo);
var qb = marklogic.queryBuilder;
function findByName(name) {
    return db.documents.query(
        qb.where(
            qb.collection('qwe'),
            qb.value('username', name)
        )
    ).result();
}
```

The problem is that it finds not only `user` or `user0`, but also `users` and if I create a document with username `book` it will find both `book` and `books`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A values query matches the entire text of a JSON property by stemming each word in the text (if stemming is enabled, which is the default).

Where (as in this case) that's not what you want, you can do either of the following:

- Create a string range index (with the root collation if you only need exact matches) for the JSON property
- Turn on word searches in the database configuration and use the "unstemmed" option on the query.

If you also turn off stemmed search in the database configuration, you don't have to pass the option (and avoid the extra resource required for both types of indexes).

To limit the configuration change to a specific property, you can configure a field for the property instead of configuring the entire database.

For more background, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/stemming

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/text_index

http://docs.marklogic.com/cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery?q=cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery&v=8.0&api=true

Hoping that helps,

Comment: Thank you, but what about escaping, since it returns results from strings like `user$)$)$($()$(""""` ? Or my approach to `search_By_Username` is wrong by design?

Comment: Try either: 1). query against a range index, or 2) index without stemming (and without wildcarding) and add the "punctuation-sensitive" option to the query.  Either approach should exclude values that differ only in the punctation -- for more about punctuation sensitivity, see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard#id_43108